# Powershell - run PsExec on multiple servers at the same time

Tags: powershell, psexec

How do I run [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) on multiple servers in parallel, and output the result to a text file? Something like:

```
ForEach ($s in $Srvs) {
    Psexec -s -d \\$s someexe.exe > \\$s\c$\temp\$s.txt
}
```

This works without the `-d` option, but soon as I add `-d`, the output is blank.

I have tried `Invoke-Command, Start-Process` etc. in a PS Workflow, but nothing works with piping option "`>`" present. I have also tried `2>` and `2>$&1`, no go.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what's happening is:

- PsExec runs on your computer.
- It creates a connection to the server and launches someexe.exe.
- That runs on the server, outputs a reply to PsExec.
- PsExec locally gets the out, and prints it on your local computer.
- That gets redirected over the network by `>` to the admin share on the server.

When you use -d, PsExec quits before getting anything back from someexe.exe, so the files end up empty.

You need to escape `>` so it is passed as a parameter to the remote command, instead of being interpreted locally. I'm not sure how to do that in PowerShell properly, in a command prompt the escape character would be `^`, and that does seem to work in PowerShell, so maybe:

```
ForEach ($s in $Srvs) {
    Psexec -s -d \\$s someexe.exe ^> \\$s\c$\temp\$s.txt
}
```

**EDIT**

OK, that's not it. Best answer I have at the moment is to put the command into a batch file, e.g. c:\scripts\myscript.bat, making it launch the command interpreter as well:

```
cmd /C someexe.exe > c:\temp\%computername%.txt
```

Then run that with PsExec, copying the batch file over:

```
ForEach ($s in $srvs) {
    psexec -s -d -c -f \\$s c:\scripts\myscript.bat
}
```

Comment: @Rishi Same thing happens for me; have updated my answer with an EDIT and another suggestion.

Comment: I agree that it would work but it defeats my purpose of creating a self dependent tool. I will have to then make the script available on all the Servers first !

Comment: @Rishi the `-c` option tells psexec to copy the script to the remote computer before running it, and `-f` to overwrite, if it exists already.